# slideshows container min-height on Joomla responsive site

Tags: joomla, responsive-design, height, containers

I've got a problem with the slideshow (JS FlexSlider) container on my responsive Joomla 3 site. 
On loadup the main content is loaded first and since the slideshow is still loading, the rest of the site is on top.
When the slideshow is ready and running, everything gets pushed downwards where it belongs.

Now since the site is responsive I can't just put a min-height to the slideshows container, since this value is changing according to the viewpoint.

Any tips on how to fix that?

[my site](http://www.lyzarr.com/testsite/)

The div class is called "bigimage" and it is placed outside any other container to have it displayed in full width.

```html
</head>
<body id="<?php echo ($itemid ? 'itemid-' . $itemid : ''); ?>">

  
    <!-- Begin Navbar-->
    <?php if ($this->countModules('position-9')): ?>
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <!-- navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top -->
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>          
            <a class="brand" href="#"><?php echo $sitename ?></a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
              <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-9" style="none" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!--End navbar-->
      <?php endif; ?>
  
        <?php if ($this->countModules('position-5')): ?>
    <div class="bigimage">
     <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-5" style="none" />
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div><!--End Bigimage-->        
    <?php endif; ?>

 <div class="container">
    
  <!-- Begin Header-->
  <div class="header">
   <div class="header-inner">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set min-height for `.bigimage` for different resolutions with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */    
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .bigimage{
         min-height: 300px;
    }  
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */

@media (min-width: 992px) { 
     .bigimage{
         min-height: 500px;
    }   
 }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .bigimage{
         min-height: 800px;
    } 
}
```

as i see it hides all elements before it starts to run. try set `.flexslider .slides > li:first-child { display: block }` to display first element of the slider while page is loading. maybe this workaround will work

Comment: Sorry, it was send before I finished my posting.Thank you, Tony. But since the .bigimage container is always on full width, those media queries aren't enough. If someone e.g. isn't running his browser window maximized, the container can have any height. Isn't there any other solution for this?

Comment: @Lyzarr as i see it hides all elements before it starts to run. try set `.flexslider .slides > li:first-child
{
  display: block
}` to display first element of the slider while page is loading. maybe this workaround will work

Comment: @Lyzarr Glad to hear it )

Comment: Please, may I ask for your help again on this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803028/logo-placement-overlapping-joomla-bootstrap ? I didn't got an answer for 2 days now, and you did an awesome job on helping me out on this one here. Sorry for this stunt, but I'm totally stuck.