# Logo placement overlapping // Joomla Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, containers, graphical-logo

On my [Joomla 3.x Bootstrap site](http://www.lyzarr.com/testsite/) I want to have a logo placed overlapping the navbar and slideshow like that:

[screenshot](http://www.lyzarr.com/stuff/testsite.jpg)

The navbar is "fixed-top" and the slideshow is placed outside any other container in order to being displayed in full width.
To make matters even more complicated, the logo should be fix on top while scrolling just like the navbar.
But on a mobile it should move up (again, like the navbar) and be even replaced by another (smaller) image.

How could this be achieved?

The logo links to home, which right now is done by putting both a href and the logo image itself in the index.php.

To change the image easily according to the viewport I'd have to do it in the css. But then how to link to home?

Please help me on getting the placement of the logo image (responsive) correctly.

```css
.logo-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 z-index:1;
} 
 
.toplogo {
   position:absolute;
   width:auto;
   height:auto;
   z-index:10;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body id="<?php echo ($itemid ? 'itemid-' . $itemid : ''); ?>">

       <div id="toplogo">
    <a href="<?php echo $root = JURI::root();?>" onfocus="blur()">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/logo-test.png" title="Zur Startseite" alt="<?php echo $root = JURI::root();?>" border="0"/>
    </a>
    </div>  
  
    <!-- Begin Navbar-->
    <?php if ($this->countModules('position-9')): ?>
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <!-- navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top -->
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>          
            <!--<a class="brand" href="#"><?php echo $sitename ?></a>-->
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
              <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-9" style="none" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!--End navbar-->
      <?php endif; ?>
  
        <?php if ($this->countModules('position-5')): ?>
    <div class="bigimage">
     <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-5" style="none" />
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div><!--End Bigimage-->        
    <?php endif; ?>

 <div class="container">
    
  <!-- Begin Header-->
  <div class="header">
   <div class="header-inner">​
```

Comment: Unfortunately no answer so far. I know it's much to ask, but I tried to get this done by myself for two days now without success. I even found another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816819/put-a-logo-on-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-without-resizing-the-navbar) but unfortunately it didn't work. What I want to achieve can also be seen here: http://www.skagosoil.gr/. In the meantime I have put the logo-link back into the navbar container...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this layout :

```
<div class="row top-menu-row"> <!-- added .row -->
    <div class="span3"> <!-- added .span3 -->
        <a class="toplogo" href="http://www.lyzarr.com/testsite/" onfocus="blur()" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute;">
            <img style="" src="/testsite/templates/test-template-joomla3-bootstrap_101/images/logo-test.png" title="Zur Startseite" alt="http://www.lyzarr.com/testsite/" border="0">
        </a>
    </div> <!-- end .span3 -->
    <div class="span9 hidden-desktop"> <!-- added .span9 -->
        <a class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
    </div> <!-- end .span9 -->
    <div class="span9"> <!-- added .span9 -->
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse" style="z-index: 2; height: 0px;">
            <ul class="nav menu  nav-tabs">
<li class="item-101 current active"><a href="/testsite/"><span>Home</span></a></li><li class="item-102 dropdown deeper parent"><a class=" dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span>About<b class="caret"></b></span></a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-103"><a href="/testsite/about/info.html"><span>Info</span></a></li></ul></li></ul>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end .span9 -->
</div>
```

Here logo goes first and menu after it. Because your bootstrap version is 2.3.2 it makes all columns 100% width if device has horizontal resolution 480px and below. Adding following styles will fix the width of your columns in percents regardless of screen resolution:

```
.top-menu-row .span3
{
    width: 22% !important;
    float: left; 
    height: auto;     
}

.top-menu-row .span9
{
    width: 74% !important;
    float: right;
}
```

and in media query for devices remove `absolute` positioning, to make your logo fit in column width:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    a.toplogo {
        position:relative;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all many thanks for helping me out again! I couldn't really look into this till now since I've been quite sick. I put in the code you provided, and at first everything looks fine (thanks!) but as soon you resize the browser window, the logo goes all wonky. I put up a gif to demonstrate this: http://www.lyzarr.com/stuff/dancing-logo.gif I checked the css, if there is anything that could cause this, but since I haven't put in any media-querys in regards to the logo so far, this doesn't seems to be the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works. The last bit (@media) doesn't actually seem to make any difference when I comment it out?! The only bit missing now is to automatically replace the logo with a different and more compact one. So I mean a real different file, like "logo_test_sm.png" that also fits into the navbar height-wise. Just scaling the logo down by media query would make it hard to read. The big one will be more like a badge, the small one should contain just the logo itself.

Comment: It should be replaced when the menu collapses and the hamburger menu is shown. (just to clarify)

Comment: @Lyzarr then you need to use a `div` with `background-image` property and set it via media query insead of `img` tag inside `a.toplogo`

Comment: Thought about that, but wasn't sure there is a solution to making the whole div a link, since putting it inside an <a href> is not valid. But found a solution for that here: http://www.digitalskydesign.com/how-to-make-an-entire-div-a-link-using-css/ . Seems to work. Now just wanna align the menu items to the left (in collapsed menu). So I put the .top-menu-row .span9 {
 width: 74% !important;
    float: right; into a media query, but then the small logo div disappears again.

Comment: 471 line in your _template.css_ you forgot closing _}_ in rule

Comment: Wow, no that's been dumb. - I can't thank you enough for you're generous help. You're really awesome. Thank you very, very much!